# How to tweet to multiple accounts using single twitter application?

Tags: php, html

I am able to tweet messages and images to twitter using a single application and one account. Just for testing purposes, I would like to know if there is a way to tweet to multiple accounts using the same application. I was thinking that we should use the access token of every single account and its corresponding secret as well. Can anyone help with this if what I am thinking is possible??

```
require_once('twitter/codebird-php/src/codebird.php');
    \Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey("xxx","xxxx");
    $cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
    $cb->setToken("xxxx", "xxxxxxxxx");

    $params = array(
    'status' => $comments,
    'media[]' => 'http://spe.atdmt.com/ds/NMMRTRUMTCRF/Azure_070114/dearazure_banner_hotub_728x90.gif'
    );
    $reply = $cb->statuses_updateWithMedia($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the token after posting (->setToken) and then post again.